# How to count number of values less than 0 and greater than 0 in a row

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have a very large dataset and I would like to generate new columns with counts of values greater than 0 and less than 0 across rows. I would then like to add another column that divides those values (e.g. above0_column / below0_column)

My data looks something like this:

```
ID SNP1 SNP2 SNP3 SNP4
1  -0.5 0.32 1.2  -0.8
2  1.5  -1.2 0.3  -0.6
3  2.6  -3.4 0.2  5.0
4  -0.3 5.0  -1.2 -0.3
```

The new columns should indicate for ID 1: 2 for <0 and 2 for >0

These are the functions I tried:

```
data$above0<-apply(data,1,function(i) sum(i>0))
```

and

```
data$above0<- Reduce('+', lapply(data,'>',0))
```

Both generated a new column, however, there were no values populated within the columns. When I looked at the column for "above0" it was filled with NAs. Is there another straightforward function I could use to generate new columns with counts >0 and <0? And ultimately column1/column2?

Comment: I edited your question for code, it often helps readability when code and data are specifically formatted as such. Please read about other [SO question formatting tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) table(sign(x)))`

Comment: I believe `rowSums` should be faster than the `apply(data,1,function(i) sum(i>0))`. Plus, to me it looks simpler

Answer (score 3):

You could use `rowSums` (which should be faster than your original `apply`) :

```
dat$gt0 <- rowSums(dat[,c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4")]>0)
dat$lt0 <- rowSums(dat[,c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4")]<0)

dat
#  ID SNP1  SNP2 SNP3 SNP4 gt0 lt0
#1  1 -0.5  0.32  1.2 -0.8   2   2
#2  2  1.5 -1.20  0.3 -0.6   2   2
#3  3  2.6 -3.40  0.2  5.0   3   1
#4  4 -0.3  5.00 -1.2 -0.3   1   3
```

There are multiple ways to select the variables you want, but I personally prefer explicitly selecting columns of interest with a character vector.

After this, the division is as simple as:

```
dat$div_gt0_lt0 <- dat$gt0 / dat$lt0
```

You could also do it in one shot without needing to create the intermediary columns if you want:

```
dat$div_gt0_lt0 <- rowSums(dat[,c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4")]>0) / rowSums(dat[,c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4")]<0)
```

Comment: I had to change it to dat$gt0 <- rowSums(dat[,2:249]>0) because I have over 200 SNP names I can't type out individually, but I'm running into the same issue that my new column "gt0" is only populated with NAs. Is there another way to use this code without typing out SNP names individually?

Comment: There are probably some `NA`s in your rows. Try adding a !is.na() condition like: `dat[,c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4")]>0 & !is.na(dat[,c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4")])`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` with `table`

```
data[c('below0', 'above0')] <- t(apply(data[-1], 1,
            function(x) table(sign(x[x!=0]))))
data
#  ID SNP1  SNP2 SNP3 SNP4 below0 above0
#1  1 -0.5  0.32  1.2 -0.8      2      2
#2  2  1.5 -1.20  0.3 -0.6      2      2
#3  3  2.6 -3.40  0.2  5.0      1      3
#4  4 -0.3  5.00 -1.2 -0.3      3      1
```

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I was thinking about that, couldn't update it earlier.  Now updated